# Selenium/Powershell/Linux: Connection refused [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:39343 (localhost:39343)

Tags: linux, powershell, selenium-webdriver, localhost

I'm trying to use a chrome driver on a linux virtual machine. I use selenium on powershell.

When I run the following command:

```
$driver = Start-SeChrome
```

Here is the result I get :

```
Connection refused [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:38481 (localhost:38481)
Connection refused [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:38481 (localhost:38481)
Connection refused [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:38481 (localhost:38481)
Connection refused [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:38481 (localhost:38481)
Connection refused [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:38481 (localhost:38481)
Connection refused [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:38481 (localhost:38481)
Connection refused [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:38481 (localhost:38481)
Connection refused [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:38481 (localhost:38481)
Connection refused [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:38481 (localhost:38481)
Connection refused [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:38481 (localhost:38481)
Connection refused [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:38481 (localhost:38481)
Connection refused [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:38481 (localhost:38481)
Starting ChromeDriver 85.0.4183.83 (94abc2237ae0c9a41c8adfb94324633-refs/branch-heads/4193@{#1758}) on port 38481
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
Connection refused [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:38481 (localhost:38481)
Connection refused [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:38481 (localhost:38481)
Connection refused [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:38481 (localhost:38481)
Connection refused [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:38481 (localhost:38481)
Connection refused [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:38481 (localhost:38481)
Connection refused [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:38481 (localhost:38481)
Connection refused [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:38481 (localhost:38481)
Connection refused [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:38481 (localhost:38481)
Connection refused [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:38481 (localhost:38481)
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
```

What's going on? I wish there were no more of these connection errors? Thanks

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue, but with MacOS, using dotnet in the terminal to run C# selenium tests using ChromeDriver.
It's really annoying - I've tried various options (headless, service.SuppressInitialDiagnosticInformation = true; log-level=3 etc.)

Once the ChromeDriver starts successfully, the test runs as normal and the messages stop appearing.
It's as though the dotnet test is trying to connect before the local server instance is able to start itself.

Comment: I've worked around this by piping the script to:  grep -wv "Connection refused"
but that's a really unpleasant workaround..